# Maven: Report using deprecated classes / methods

Tags: maven, deprecated

I want to know if there is any kind of report on maven that show's me the classes and methods that I'm using that is deprecated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Normally you see deprecation warnings in the IDE, but you can also add [showDeprecation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#showDeprecation) parameter to the Maven compiler plugin section. Then those warnings will be shown in the log.

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.1</version>
     <configuration>
         <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Then you can generate build report from that javac output using reporting plugins on CI server. For example Jenkins [Warning Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin).

Comment: This is a nice stuff but what i want is something that generate a report to be used on the site, or some plugin that generate an XML so I can use it. Do you know something that do this?

Comment: You can use CI server to process build log and generate various reports.

Comment: Eugene, I use Jenkins, do you know how can I do this on Jenkins or Hudson?

Comment: Maven should be applauded for choosing the 200 character XML option (above) that no-one knows, in preference to the 18 character option (-Xlint:deprecation) that everyone knows.

Answer (score 2):

Sonar includes an engine called squid, which according to an [article](http://www.sonarsource.org/detect-dead-code-and-calls-to-deprecated-methods-with-sonar-squid/) I found, locates and reports on usage of deprecated methods.  I haven't used Sonar yet (it's on my list of things to learn) but teammates of mine like it a lot.